# Getting Websocket Failure when trying to anonymously authenticate user using AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to anonymously authenticate users using AngularFire. I want to authenticate a user only once (so, if the user has already been authenticated, a new uid won't be generated). When I use the code below, I get a `previous_websocket_failure` notification. I also get an error in the console that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null`. When the page is refreshed, everything works fine.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

```
app.factory('Ref', ['$window', 'fbURL', function($window, fbURL) {
  'use strict';
  return new Firebase(fbURL);
 }]);

app.service('Auth', ['$q', '$firebaseAuth', 'Ref', function ($q, $firebaseAuth, Ref) {
  var auth = $firebaseAuth(Ref);
  var authData = Ref.getAuth();
  console.log(authData);

  if (authData) {
  console.log('already logged in with ' + authData.uid);
  } else {
    auth.$authAnonymously({rememberMe: true}).then(function() {
     console.log('authenticated');
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error');
    });
  }
}]);

app.factory('Projects', ['$firebaseArray', '$q', 'fbURL', 'Auth', 'Ref', function($firebaseArray, $q, fbURL, Auth, Ref) {
  var authData = Ref.getAuth();
  var ref = new Firebase(fbURL + '/projects/' + authData.uid);
  console.log('authData.uid: ' + authData.uid);
  return $firebaseArray(ref);
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Projects factory, you have assumed `authData` will not be null. There are no guarantees here, since your Projects factory is initialized as soon as you inject it into another provider. I also noticed that your Auth service doesn't actually return anything. This probably means that the caller has to know the internal workings and leads to quite a bit of coupling. A more SOLID structure would probably be as follows:

```
app.factory('Projects', function(Ref, $firebaseArray) {
   // return a function which can be invoked once
   // auth is resolved
   return function(uid) {
      return $firebaseArray(Ref.child('projects').child(uid));
   }
});

app.factory('Auth', function(Ref, $firebaseAuth) {
   return $firebaseAuth(Ref);
});

app.controller('Example', function($scope, Auth, Projects) {
   if( Auth.$getAuth() === null ) {
     auth.$authAnonymously({rememberMe: true}).then(init)
        .catch(function(error) {
           console.log('error');
        });
   }
   else {
      init(Auth.$getAuth());
   }

   function init(authData) {
      // when auth resolves, add projects to the scope
      $scope.projects = Projects(authData.uid);
   }
});
```

Note that dealing with auth in your controllers and services should generally be discouraged and dealing with this [at the router level](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes) is a more elegant solution. **I'd highly recommend investing in this approach.** Check out [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) for some example code.