# Editing particular record from list with Firebase and Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to allow users to edit their records in Firebase by clicking on an edit button next to the particular record (a modal then displays the editable information). When I use the code below, the console log shows `projectIndex = -1`, which I think means that the record I'm looking for can't be found. Any suggestions on how to modify this code to access the correct record?

```
.controller('EditProjectCtrl',
  function ($stateParams, Projects, $modalInstance, Auth) {

    var editProject = this;

    if( Auth.$getAuth() === null ) {
      Auth.$authAnonymously({rememberMe: true}).then(init)
       .catch(function(error) {
         console.log('error');
     });
   }
   else {
     init(Auth.$getAuth());
   }

    function init(authData) {
     editProject.projects = Projects(authData.uid);
   }

   var projectId = $stateParams.projectId, projectIndex;
   console.log(projectId) // displays something like this: -JpntT-F7KQe1KlA69uk
   projectIndex = editProject.projects.$indexFor(projectId);
   console.log(projectIndex);
   editProject.project = editProject.projects[projectIndex];
// . . . 
})
.factory('Projects', function(Ref, $firebaseArray) {

  return function(uid) {
   return $firebaseArray(Ref.child('projects').child(uid));
  };
    })
```

For what it's worth, when I used the original code in this [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279725/getting-websocket-failure-when-trying-to-anonymously-authenticate-user-using-ang) of mine, I was able edit records without a problem (I updated that code because it was causing authentication issues).

Comment: Just a side note: Is this the full code or a portion of it? I ask because the controller declaration is not closed.

Comment: @Sinan Bolel Thanks for pointing that out. This is just a portion of the code. I just edited the post to close the declaration.

Comment: [Page one of the AngularFire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro) You can't synchronously call console.log() on data that is being downloaded from a server asynchronously. Also, what is the point of this? If you want the specific record, why not just ask for that one instead of downloading them all and trying to pick it out? `$firebaseObject( ref.child($stateParams.projectId) )` Why so much convoluted assigning and duplication in editProject? KISS FTW.

Comment: @Kato Thanks for clarifying. There's so much convoluted assigning and duplication because I'm still learning Angular (and apparently still have a long way to go. . . ). I was trying to use the code on the first page of the Angular site as an example. I'll use your suggested code instead. Incidentally, I just noticed a minor typo on [page one of the AngularFire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/intro-to-angularfire.html#section-async-intro). The last part of "so there is no need to worry about when it be available" should be ". . . when it **will** be available

Answer (score 1):

From the [AngularFire documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey):

> `$getRecord(key)`
>
> Returns the record from the array for the given key. If the key is not found, returns `null`. This method utilizes `$indexFor(key)` to find the appropriate record.

I believe your service should have a `retrieveRecord` function to check if a record exist or not. This being said if you already have the record - doesn't that mean it already exist? in which case you should have a edit function in your factory and then call it from your controller with the appropriate parameters.

Also, remember that queries night need to be used with the `$loaded()` function because of asynchronicity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the records are there. But my code is wrong because it's not finding those records. Hence, `projectIndex = -1`. `console.log(editProject.projects)` displays the array containing that user's records, but the code I'm using isn't finding the relevant record within that array.